# How to make Bourbaki's style remarks

Tags: indentation, theorems

I like my remarks comes in the fashion of Bourbaki's. Lines and the "Remark" are indented inwards equally, and the font is one size smaller. I used these simple lines of code:

```
\newtheoremstyle{myrem}%name
 {3pt}%Space above
 {3pt}%Space below
 {\small}%Body font
 { }%Indent amount
 {\itshape}% Theorem head font
 {:}%Punctuation after theorem head
 { }%Space after theorem head 2
 { }%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
 \theoremstyle{myrem}{\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}}
```

Then

```
\begin{document}%
 Some texts here.
\begin{remark}%
\leftskip\parindent%
All Bourbaki type comments are flushed left with hanging indent come here. 
Moreover, they are numbered, as I wished. But is there a way to make
\leftskip\parindent
automatic, as part of the style? Since, the book has been finished.
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

This works all right but should be added to all the "Remarks." I do not want to use the ntheorem package since it creates conflicts difficult to resolve. Further, I like to know how to put the Bourbaki's dangerous zone `\danger` in the margin (but this is easy to find out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `etoolbox` to expand the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheoremstyle{myrem}%name
 {3pt}%Space above
 {3pt}%Space below
 {\small}%Body font
 { }%Indent amount
 {\itshape}% Theorem head font
 {:}%Punctuation after theorem head
 { }%Space after theorem head 2
 {}%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

 \theoremstyle{myrem}
 \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
 \appto\remark{\leftskip\parindent}


\begin{document}%
 Some texts here.
\begin{remark}%
All Bourbaki type comments are flushed left with hanging indent come here. Moreover, they are numbered, as I wished. But is there a way to make 
\begin{verbatim}
  \leftskip\parindent
\end{verbatim}
automatic, as part of the style? Since, the book has been finished.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```